# Unwanted Mobile Site Redirection, Unsure How to Debug and Remove

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I recently launched a new Wordpress website: http://www.truescan3d.com/

We recently found it was producing a server error page when navigating from Google via mobile device (at least iphone). This is due to it redirecting to http://m.truescan3d.com/ which does not exist and has never existed. This only happens via Google on mobile devices.

I am unsure how the redirection got set up and am consequently unsure how to resolve the issue.

Some brief history. The domain is hosted by network solutions. The hosting is via GoDaddy Virtual Server using WHM and cPanel. The domain recently pointed to an older version, different theme Wordpress install on the same hosting platform as well as a Wix website.

I am not too familiar with redirection for mobile devices so I am not completely sure where all I should be looking.

**I have checked the .htaccess file, nothing seems nonstandard to a Wordpress install:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**I have looked through the  section looking for an sort of redirection code but have found nothing.** I would imagine if it was here that it would redirect upon any navigation to the website on a mobile device instead of just Google. The theme is responsive and I am fairly certain nothing like this is in there.

**I have re-indexed the website in Google Webmaster Tools.**

As far as I can tell there is no solid way to trace redirection for mobile devices, so I have not been able to find any information on the redirect itself.

***Your help and insights are greatly appreciated!***

**Edit: The domain was previously pointing to Wix nameservers. There was an m. subdomain on wix. I believe that google is forcing or caching this redirect to the mobile site domain even though it is non existent. Temporarily I added the m. subdomain to point to the main website, but as you know Wordpress can't work fully in a separate domain name. I need to figure out how to clear Googles cache of this old redirect.**

Tim

Comment: Disable all your plugins and switch to a default theme (Twenty Twelve / Twenty Thirteen).  If the problem goes away, switch back to your theme, and re-activate your plugins one by one.  When the problem returns, you'll have a) your culprit and b) a better idea what question(s) you should be asking -- either here or in the theme/plugin's support forums.

Comment: I already did this, still redirects. Theme developer confirmed that the theme has no redirect features.

Comment: Have you tried it in a different browser? Perhaps on a different computer?

Comment: The issue only happens on mobile phones. I have tried multiple different devices on different networks. Every time when clicking from google there is a redirect to http://m.truescan3d.com/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem even though Google still attempted to display the mobile site.

I simply added the m. subdomain to the A record and then redirected the m. subdomain to the main domain via a 301 redirect in cPanel.